# could not locate gemfile in ruby tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Im doing the railstutorial.org chap 2 toy app, everything from chapter 1 went fine, but when I tried to install bundle for the toy app, I got this

naylen@rails-tutorial:~/workspace/hello_app (master) $ cd ~/workspace
naylen@rails-tutorial:~/workspace $ rails *4.2.0.rc3* new toy_app
(it installed all the files)

than I put:
naylen@rails-tutorial:~/workspace $ toy_app/
naylen@rails-tutorial:~/workspace $ bundle install --without production
Could not locate Gemfile

I copied the same instructions I got for the gemfile from the book, which is this:
source

'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails',        '4.2.0.rc3'

gem 'sass-rails',   '5.0.0.beta1'

gem 'uglifier',     '2.5.3'

gem 'coffee-rails', '4.1.0'

gem 'jquery-rails', '4.0.0.beta2'

gem 'turbolinks',   '2.3.0'

gem 'jbuilder',     '2.2.3'

gem 'sdoc',         '0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3',     '1.3.9'
  gem 'byebug',      '3.4.0'
  gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'
  gem 'spring',      '1.1.3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end

and still it said that it could not locate the file.
I refreshed and tried again, and I got this:

naylen@rails-tutorial:~/workspace $ cd ~/workspace
naylen@rails-tutorial:~/workspace $ rails *4.2.0.rc3* new toy_app
       exist

identical  README.rdoc

identical  Rakefile

identical  config.ru

identical  .gitignore

```
conflict  Gemfile
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you create the app, you need to change into its directory to execute Bundler commands.

(Based on the excerpts in your question, it appears that you're still in `workspace`, while the Gemfile is located in `toy_app`.)

For example:

```
$ rails new blah_app
$ cd blah_app
$ bundle (whatever)
```

Comment: thank you! I actually went back and deleted all the files in the workplace and everything worked fine from there, I think I had written a wrong command before and things were not falling into place...